# How to sumbit a form to blockchain using jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, ethereum

I have developed a web application using React on top of Ethereum blockchain.

One of the pages in my application gets information from user like this:

```
class AssetNew extends Component {
 state = {
  name: "",
  description: "",
  manufacturer: "",
  price: "",
  errorMessage: ""
 };

 onSubmit = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const { name, description, manufacturer, price} = this.state;
  this.setState({errorMessage: "" });

  try {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    await tracker.methods
      .createAsset(name, description, manufacturer, price)
      .send({
       from: accounts[0],
       value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.price, "ether"),
       gas: "1000000"
     });
 } catch (err) {
   this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
 }
};

render() {
return (
     <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
       <Form.Field>
         <label>Name</label>
         <Input
           value={this.state.name}
           onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value })}
        />
       </Form.Field>
       .... // three more from.field for description, manufacturer and price
 );
 }
}
export default AssetNew;
```

This page gets name, description, manufacturer, and price and sends it to the smart contract to register a new product. Everything works fine with the browser (I can create a new product with the form).
However, I am not able to create a new product with Jmeter.
I tried to send parameters with POST Method:

[image]

After running the test Http requests are successful but nothing happens (I expect Jmeter to create a new product).

Should I expect Jmeter to create a new product by passing parameters? 
Do I check the performance correctly?

Smart contract to create a new product:

```
contract AssetTracker {
  uint public id;
  uint nonce;
  struct Asset {
    string name;
    string description;
    string manufacture;
    uint price;
    uint id;
    address owner;
    bool initialized;
 }
 Asset[] public assets;

 function createAsset(string name, string description, string manufacture, uint price) public payable{

    id = uint(keccak256(now, msg.sender, nonce)) % 1000;
    nonce++;
    Asset memory newAsset = Asset(name, description, manufacture, price, id, msg.sender, true);
    assets.push(newAsset);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to send the request using the browser, you should be able to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) in order to capture the relevant [HTTP POST Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) and generate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature

   - From JMeter's main menu choose File - Templates - Recording and click "Create"
   - Expand HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare your browser for recording. Configure it to use JMeter as the proxy

   - `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the proxy host
   - `8888` as the proxy port
   - make sure that the proxy is set to all protocols and there are no exceptions
   - If you plan to record HTTPS traffic - import `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` certificate into your browser, the certificate is generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

   [image]
3. Execute the request in browser
4. JMeter should capture the request and store the HTTP Request sampler under Thread Group - Recording Controller.

More information: [Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

Alternatively you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) for creating the test plan, in this case you will not have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation.